# How to configure JShell in Intellij for a multimodule project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jshell

How can I configure JShell in IntelliJ to work with our complex multi-module Maven project?

I have set "Use classpath of: " to "<whole project>".

How should I setup the "Project settings > Libraries"?

At the moment it lists all our Maven dependencies.

I hope I'm not suppose to add all the "target/classes" dirs of our dozens of modules.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem